# ASP.NET 5 RC1 + VS 2015 Update 1: xproj cannot be opened

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 + all of the following updates (also upgraded the dnvm) and I want to create a new asp.net 5 web application.

When I start to create it Visual Studio 2015 returns an error:

> \WebApplication.xproj cannot be opened. The project type is not supported by this installation.

I've tried the method in which you delete the contains of the `ComponentModelCache` folder - no success so far.

Comment: Restart machine. Run the installer on get.asp.net. If already installed select the repair option

Comment: Did that. Didn't work out. After that I event uninstalled asp.net 5 and installed it again from get.asp.net - still gives me the same error. @firste

Comment: Are you using Resharper?

Comment: No. Clean VS 2015 install + just the necessary updates

Comment: New project or old beta1 project?

Comment: Brand new. I can neither create new or open an old one. Everything is updated to the latest version.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as  "a problem that can no longer be reproduced".  VS 2015 Update 3 has been released and should be used for ASP.NET Core  development.